# What is acceptable set of values $E[ \max(X-4,0)]$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable such that for $d \in [0,3] \cup [6,10]$ we have $E[\max(X-d,0)] = \frac{(10-d)^2}{20}$.

What can you say about $E[ \max(X-4,0)]$ (what is acceptable set of values $E[ \max(X-4,0)]$ ?

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of expected value,
$$E[\max(X-d,0)] = \int_d^\infty (x-d) p(x)\mathop{dx}$$ where $p(x)$ is the probability density function for $X$.

$$\frac {(10-6)^2}{20} = \int_6^\infty (x-6) p(x) \mathop{dx} \le \int_4^\infty (x-4) p(x)  \mathop{dx} \le \int_3^\infty (x-3) p(x) \mathop{dx} = \frac{(10-3)^2}{20}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{28}{16}\leqslant E((X-4)^+)\leqslant\frac{31}{16}$$